# ABAP CDS conversion timestamp into Date & Time

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, cds

I've got the following field in my CDS View:

[image]

Now when I'm consuming that View in my Fiori Elements app, the data in that field is displayed as following:

[image]

Is there any annotation or `CAST` function in order to fix it and to display timestamp properly as date & time? Within one column?

Would appreciate any kind of help!

Thanks and BR.

Comment: Did you try adding Semantics Annotation (e.g. Semantics.businessDate.at) and see if it works? More details are [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/691cb949c1034198800afde3e5be6570/2.0.04/en-US/57f00f85b92c4ee9a8b069f212b59573.html)

Comment: unfortunatelly it did not work either. But I solve the issue with cast/substring: cast(substring(cast(_TranspOrdExecution.actualdate as abap.char( 17 )), 1, 8) as abap.dats)  as actualeventdate

Comment: post your solution then, it is not clear how did you consume that view